# Optimizing search algorithm for guessing list of strings via function returning bool if substring is in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, search

I trying to figure out the most effective way to accomplish this task:

A function, `check()`, contains a list of strings. Calling the function with a string as argument, will return `True` if the argument string is part of any of the strings in the list. `False` if not.

Here's my code:

```
import string
from tqdm import tqdm


def check(text):
    """Returns True if input text is part of any of the strings in the list"""
    strings = ["we ", "_want", "t0", "gu@ess", "these-", "str1ngs"]
    return any(text in substring for substring in strings)


def remove_partials(input_list):
    """Removes strings from the input list they are a substring of any other string in the list"""
    substrings = []
    for item in input_list:
        for item_2 in input_list:
            if item != item_2 and item_2 in item:
                substrings.append(item_2)

    for partial in substrings:
        try:
            input_list.remove(partial)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return input_list


charset = f"{string.ascii_lowercase}{string.digits}@-_. "
known = charset
tried = []
result = []


while len(known) > 0:
    found = []

    for prefix in (pbar_2 := (tqdm(known, leave=False))):
        pbar_2.set_description(prefix)

        for char in (pbar := (tqdm(charset, leave=False))):

            substring = f"{prefix}{char}"
            pbar.set_description(char)

            if substring not in tried:

                if check(substring) and substring not in found:
                    tqdm.write(f"{substring}")
                    found.append(substring)
                    result.append(substring)

            tried.append(substring)

    known = found

print()
print(remove_partials(result))
```

I want to guess the content of that list in as few checks as possible, using the `check()` function, knowing only the charset (`alphanumeric` + `-_@.[space]`) and displaying the progress (I'm using [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)).

My code does accomplish this, but it is very inefficient. For example if "strings" is in the list, it performs checks for both "tring", "string" and "trings", which I feel like could be optimized.